# How to get Webserver's IP in java Application

Tags: java, load-balancing

I need to get Webserver's IP in the application server. Our application structure is like below:

We have 2 Load Balancers and under each Load Balancer, we have 3 Webservers each and under these 6 Webserver's we have 3 Application Servers.

Now from:

```
request.getRemoteAddr(); // This gives me the client IP
InetAddress.getLocalHost(); // This gives me my application server IP
request.getHeader("X-FORWARDED-FOR"); // and this gives me null value
```

I want to get my Webserver Ip as well to check from which Webserver I am getting the request. Can someone please help me how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

`ServletRequest` knows `getServerName()` and `getServerPort()`:

> Returns the host name of the server to which the request was sent. It
>   is the value of the part before ":" in the Host header value, if any,
>   or the resolved server name, or the server IP address.

Additionally it has `getLocalAddr()` (and `getLocalPort()` and `getLocalName()`)

> Returns the Internet Protocol (IP) address of the interface on which
>   the request was received.

When used on your application server `getLocalAddr()`will give you the IP of the app server, but you can try if `getServerName()` returns the webserver address.

Comment: it is giving me the Application server IP and not the Webserver Ip's. Could you please suggest something else.

Comment: What is the difference between getServerName and getLocalName

Comment: Someone please help me in this.